# how to customize laravel passport respone on token expire

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-passport

how to chage laravel passport response on access_token expire from

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

to

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Access Token expires",
}
```

Comment: modify the middleware

Comment: and how to do that?? i have no idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom exception handling in your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` class. Add the following function if not already present. You are basicly catching the Authentication exception, and adding your own transformation to it.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'type' => 'error',
                'status' => Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED,
                'message' => 'Access Token expires',
            ],
            Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is the exception you want to catch, if not working please get back to me and we figure something out :)

Comment: perfect, if it helped please accept it as an answer :)